# How to center this piece of text in ShareLateX (editor) or Latex (in general)?

Tags: text, format, latex, centering, sharelatex

I am writing a resume and want to center text at the top of the document which contains my name and email details, like this

[image]

I used \begin{center} and \end{center} but it doesnt seem to work

Here is my code:

---

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}

\vspace{-4mm}
\textbf{\LARGE Samuel Adams}
\\
 & \\  \textbf{Notsville, TX} $|$
\textbf{\phone \ \ +1 (000) 000 0000} $|$ 
\textbf{cxcx@gmail.com} $|$  \textbf{{www.linkedin.com/ffdfs}}\\

\end{tabular*}

\vspace{1 mm}
```

---

Can anyone help me center this piece of text?

This is how it looks right now. I am looking to center both lines just like we do it in word.

Comment: Can you make a sketch how the result should look like?

Comment: ...and please also add a [mre] so we can see what page dimensions you have

Comment: Hello SamCarter! The image is added to the top of the post. Let me know if you are able to access it

Comment: Please add a [mre] to your question, not in comments which will remove all line breaks. Please also make sure that the [mre] is actually compilable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table will be in the middle of the page once

- you make the left and right margin the same size
- use `\noindent` in front of the table to avoid it being indented as the first line of a new paragraph

(I'm actually not sure why you use a table for this, you never use the second column...)

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article} 
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage} 
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{url} 
\usepackage{wasysym} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[a4paper,bindingoffset=0.3in, left=0.5in,right=0.5in,top =0.8in,bottom=-5in, footskip=.25in]{geometry} 

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
\textbf{\LARGE Samuel Adams} & \\
\textbf{Notsville, TX} $|$ \textbf{\phone \ \ +1 (000) 000 0000} $|$ 
\textbf{cxcx@gmail.com} $|$ \textbf{{www.linkedin.com/ffdfs}} & \\
\hline
\end{tabular*}

\vspace{1 mm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help samcarter! I removed the table and made the suggested changes. Text is now center aligned